React fetch raising SyntaxError
I have a node server running on my own home server with access via noip. http://bmraapi.ddns.net/fuel/acceptances/fuel/BIOMASS/y/2024/m/08/d/11 will return data in chrome and postman. However when I use fetch in react as follows, the await response.json() returns SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.
Im struggling how to diagnose the issue as response is returning something but don't understand it
const response = await fetch("http://bmraapi.ddns.net/fuel/acceptances/fuel/BIOMASS/y/2024/m/08/d/11",
  {
     mode: "no-cors",
  }
);
let bidOffer = await response.json();


Sorry I had a powercutjust after my post that stopped my internet, now back up and access available to bmraapi.ddns.net but still have the same issue

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
